# To normalize or not normalize? What performs better?

Tags: sql, performance, normalization

Would multiple, joined, normalized tables return queries faster than 1 denormalized table? I'm interested in the performance of read (select) statement, not insert, delete, update.

I believe the normalized, joined tables return select queries faster, but I've also heard that since all of the data is in one row with 1 denormalized table, that denormalized tables return queries faster.

I'm trying to find this out, so I can improve visualization rendering on Tableau, so I'm concerned with the read operations of the table, not write.

Any clearing up on this confusion would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Normalized tables are faster sometimes.  Denormalized tables are faster sometimes.  If you have a particular problem, with specified data, and a query you want, then you can post that as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty obvious that the fastest way to get a query result is if it has already been pre-built and is sitting ready for retrieval in a single table.

However, from a maintenance perspective that is not practical.

It is generally good advice to keep most data in normalized tables, but see DRapp's answer for scenarios where denormalization is sometimes used.

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with static data warehouse, sometimes it IS better to deal with denormalized data, especially with any type of aggregations / roll-up values you may be interested in within the data.  Having pre-summarized tables on very large datasets is good, but without knowing more of the context of your data, as best I can offer as an answer.

To clarify from your comment...

Lets say you are dealing with (ex: something I worked with in the past) government contract and grants data for the year 2010-2012.  The data itself is not going to change... who awarded, gov't sector, small/large business classification, amount awarded, etc.  These values won't really change, so if you wanted to know which companies were awarded how much per gov't congressional district, per state, per industry, etc.  Having pre-aggregate totals would save time.

Having a read-only display system (querying only) from another system that is performing the data entry (such as sales activity that DOES the insert/update/delete), you should obviously stay in a normalized mode as the underlying data IS changing.. again even though you are giving read-only inquiry access to it.

Comment: The context of my situation is that I'm trying to find out which table type will work best with Tableau when users are rendering the visualizations from data in our server. Tableau is a read only program, so I'm not concerned with insert, delete and updates.

Comment: If raw retrieval performance is all that matters and transactional data integrity is not a key issue: Did you look into NoSQL data storage solutions such as MongoDB?

Comment: @chris I have not, but I don't think my boss is interested in changing data platforms. We work with SQL Server.

Comment: @DRapp so if my data was not changing, would you suggest a normalized or denormalized table?

Comment: Again, as everyone else has pointed out, this can't be answered with a general statement.

Comment: @pbars23, it depends on a variety of factors too short listed here.  Volume of data... Are you talking 100k records vs several million.  What is the context of the data, are there many "lookup" tables for getting descriptions for "ID"-based fields, etc.  How many lookup tables...  What are you trying to present the user.

Comment: @DRapp There are several millions (if not more) rows of data. There are one lookup table for each table. Just the 1 lookup table made from the primary key on each table. We presenting multiple visualizations: maps, pie charts, bar chart, line graphs. Also, the visualizations will more than likely filter the total amount of data being used, so complex where clauses may be used.

Comment: Then I would suggest you simply test it. If benchmarks show that denormalization gives you a significant performance boost, it may be justified to denormalize. Everything else is just guessing.

Comment: @chris It really is all just guessing until you get into the actually testing of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's very dependent on the situation, as others have pointed out. The best thing you can do if you need top-notch performance is generate some tests to see how things work out and then implement the fastest solution. Create one set of denormalized tables, one set of normalized, and run some queries and see how fast they execute. Go from there.

However, unless you have TONS of data, speed is probably not your biggest concern. Modern RDBMS's are extremely efficient, especially with the appropriate indexes, etc. in place. You might be better off asking whether normalized or de-normalized tables make more logical sense for the work you are doing. You might also consider that one of the biggest arguments for normalized tables is that they help prevent data errors. Consider doing some background reading on normalization for an explanation of this. If you want to make sure your data is as clean as possible, you may want to normalize, even if you take a small performance hit.